# SVN export - overwrite files but not delete directory

Tags: svn, deployment

We have 2 directories in an SVN repository containing same subdirectory structure. As part of our (primitive) deployment scripts, we svn export the first one into a local directory, followed by an svn export of the 2nd one into the same local directory:

```
repo/project/trunk/dir1/
repo/project/trunk/dir1/a/
repo/project/trunk/dir1/a/foo.txt

repo/project/trunk/dir2/
repo/project/trunk/dir2/a/
repo/project/trunk/dir2/a/foo.txt
```

In our scenario, dir1 is a production version of some files, and dir2 and pending changes to those files yet-to-be-released by the Development team. Thus, we want svn export to overwrite the files on disk.

svn export will not populate an existing directory; the --force flag is required. 
svn export --force will not fill an existing directory, it *recreates* the directory entirely. Thus, our 2nd svn export destroys the local export of dir1 and leaves us with the contents of dir2 alone.

Is there any way to make svn export do what we want-- get files from dir1, put them in a local directory, and overlay the contents of dir2 on top of dir1?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `svn export` will allow for that behaviour. short of using actual branches, would it be acceptable to use `rsync` to create a third "combined" directory?

something along these lines:

```
# export 'dir1' to 'production'
svn export repo/project/trunk/dir1 production
# export 'dir2' to 'development'
svn export repo/project/trunk/dir2 development

# sync contents from 'production' to 'combined'
rsync -a production/ combined
# sync contents from 'development' to 'combined'
rsync -a development/ combined
```

Comment: This is our current workaround, except we're using xcopy to combine the contents instead of rsync.